# Sent messages are coming back.(XMPP + Ejabberd)

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

Sometimes sent messages in my chat application are coming back.

Message type:chat Ejabberd-15.07

Here is the Error.

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="user2@local-mbp" 
to="user1@local-mbp/27165765321442393248102225" 
type="error"><body>Hey</body><error code="503" 
type="cancel"><service-unavailable 
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></message>
```

When this happens i can see user1 offline in my app but in ejabberd (web admin/virtual hosts) the user1 is online.i have mod_offline enabled in the configuration.

```
mod_offline: 
access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages

## Maximum number of offline messages that users can have:
max_user_offline_messages: 
admin: 5000
all: 100
```

No idea what is going on here but it seems like the problem is at server side.Could anyone please help me with this or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you please add the type of message you are sending and the version of ejabberd you are using ?

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Hey please see my edit.Thanks

Comment: You did not say what type of message you are using. Try with message type=chat

Comment: i did, in the second line of question.and yes i am using message type = chat.  @MickaëlRémond